Planner embed in sharepoint
I am trying to embed planner into sharepoint. I added iframe in the beginning and end of my address, and tried to embed it, but it's showing tasks is not responding. In the sharepoint site settings, iframe from tasks.office.com is already enabled. So any way I could embed the planner. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Already tried adding by clicking "+New" from the sharepoint site, but unfortunately there is no "plan" option in that. Probably the administrator has disabled it.
